# Figure visibility with corrplot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to save a correlation matrix figure without displaying it. For regular plots I use:

```
fig1 = figure('visible','off');
plot(x,y);
saveas(fig1,'name','fig');
saveas(fig1,'name','epsc');
```

This however doesn't work with `corrplot`. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

`corrplot` creates a new figure so if you want visibility to be turned off when the figure is created, you'll want to set the `DefaultFigureVisible` property to `'off'` and then back to on after the figure is created. While this settings is active, any new figure that opens will be hidden by default.

```
set(0, 'DefaultFigureVisible', 'off')
corrplot(data)
set(0, 'DefaultFigureVisible', 'on')
```

Alternately, you could try to toggle the visibility immediately after creating the figure

```
corrplot(data)
set(gcf, 'Visible', 'off')
```

Depending on the internals of `corrplot`, this second option could toggle the visibility before the figure is actually rendered.

Comment: That works great with not displaying corrplot, but I am still struggling to save it as .fig and .eps.

Comment: @Agnieszka What command are you trying to save it with? You should use `saveas(gcf, 'name', 'fig')` *not* `saveas(fig1, 'name', 'fig')` because MATLAB is not actually placing the `corrplot` in `fig1`

Comment: @Agnieszka If this worked for you consider marking it as the solution